# Encontrar primeiro valor maior que um determinado número no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma planilha do Excel para cálculo de armaduras de aço para estruturas de concreto. Por meio de cálculo, eu acho um valor de área de aço por m². A partir deste valor, pretendo encontrar numa lista de valores pré-determinados aquele que me atende, ou seja, que seja o primeiro valor maior ou igual ao encontrado. Eu consigo encontrar o valor com a função SE, só que fica enorme e com várias condicionais, dada a grande quantidade de valores. Então, se alguém souber de uma forma mais simplificada, agradeço.
Abaixo segue imagens para melhor compreensão:

[image: Imagem_1]

[image: Imagem_2]

P.S.: Vale lembrar que, como eu escolho a bitola de aço, quero uma função que procure numa coluna específica. Como escolhi 10mm, o valor encontrado deverá estar na Coluna S

Comment: Qual a fórmula utilizada atualmente? E onde você escolhe a bitola? Alguma célula ou na fórmula?

Comment: Não estou utilizando nenhuma fórmula no momento. Estou escolhendo manualmente por meio da consulta à tabela. Eu escolho a bitola por meio de Caixa de Combinação (Controle de Formulário). Essa escolha me dá um número na célula de vínculo, o qual corresponderá à coluna na qual irei procurar o valor.

Comment: Então você utiliza código em VBA? no formulário? Edite a pergunta com estas informações

Comment: Não. Não é um controle ActiveX. Eu não sei trabalhar com VBA.

Comment: Quanto à bitola selecionada não há problema. O que eu quero resolver é encontrar uma função que compare os valores da coluna S (digamos q a tabela tem só uma coluna, para simplificar o entendimento) com o que eu tenho, ou seja, que ele compare desde o menor valor (2,42) ao maior valor (16,00), dessa coluna, e me retorne o imediatamente superior ao calculado.

Comment: Eu tentei usar o PROCV, com Correspondência Aproximada (já que não tenho o valor exato de 8,86 na coluna em questão), mas ele me retorna sempre o menor valor dessa coluna (2,42), que obviamente é inferior ao que eu tenho (8,86).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUÇÃO ENCONTRADA: ÍNDICE + CORRESP**

Muito obrigado aos amigos que tentaram solucionar meu problema, mas consegui desenrolar, depois de muito quebrar minha cabeça, uma vez que já tinha tentado resolver esse mesmo problema em outras planilhas minhas e em tabelas mais complicadas que essa, com várias entradas. O segredo da solução está no uso da função **CORRESP**, pois com ela, eu consigo encontrar em que linha está o menor valor de área de aço maior que o calculado, simplesmente utilizando o **TIPO DE CORRESPONDÊNCIA -1(É MAIOR DO QUE)**, no último argumento da fórmula. Dessa forma eu utilizo tal valor na função **ÍNDICE**, na qual eu tenho como matriz todos os meus dados, a linha o valor dado pelo **CORRESP** e a coluna o valor dado pela célula vinculada ao **Controle de Formulário**, na qual a bitola é selecionda pelo usuário, acrescido e 1 unidade

**DETERMINAÇÃO DA ÁREA DE AÇO EFETIVA:**

```
=SEERRO(ÍNDICE($N$5:$T$34;CORRESP(I21;SE(U12=1;$O$5:$O$34;SE(U12=2;$P$5:$P$34;SE(U12=3;$Q$5:$Q$34;SE(U12=4;$R$5:$R$34;SE(U12=5;$S$5:$S$34;SE(U12=6;$T$5:$T$34))))));-1);U12+1);"Selecione uma bitola de aço maior")
```

Na função **CORRESP** dessa fórmula, o usuário escolhe uma bitola, que corresponde a um número da célula vinculada do Controle de Formulário (Caixa de Combinação - Não é Controle **ACTIVEX**). Assim, a bitola 4,2mm corresponde ao índice 1, 5mm índice 2 e assim por diante. Isso irá definir a coluna na qual a **CORRESP** fará a busca. Na função geral **ÍNDICE**, o último argumento da função que solicita a coluna, onde contém o dado que eu quero, é acrescido de uma unidade, pois a bitola escolhida pelo usuário corresponde,  na tabela, ao seu índice mais 1, ou seja, 4,2mm é índice 1, mas na tabela é coluna 2, 5mm é índice 2, mas na tabela é coluna 3 e assim por diante **(COLUNA=índice+1)**.
A função **SEERRO** foi usada para o caso da maior área de aço tabelado da bitola selecionada seja inferior ao calculado, solicitando ao usuário a escolha de uma bitola maior.
A função **CORRESP** me retorna, para os valores em destaque abaixo, as **linhas 9 e 13** da tabela, respectivamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É claro que essa **Tabela** **Auxiliar** não será visualizada pelo usuário, assim como o índice da seleção da bitola. Coloquei para melhor compreensão do que fiz. Eu optei pela função **ÍNDICE** ao ínvés da **PROCV** pois me permite procurar dados para a esquerda e assim determinar automaticamente o espaçamento das barras (Coluna 1), que é outro dado que também me interessa. Assim foram utilizadas a mesma função acima, com alteração apenas do último argumento da fórmula, que agora é  **Coluna 1 (Espaçamento) da Tabela.**

**DETERMINAÇÃO DO ESPAÇAMENTO:**

```
=SEERRO(ÍNDICE($N$5:$T$34;CORRESP(I21;SE(U12=1;$O$5:$O$34;SE(U12=2;$P$5:$P$34;SE(U12=3;$Q$5:$Q$34;SE(U12=4;$R$5:$R$34;SE(U12=5;$S$5:$S$34;SE(U12=6;$T$5:$T$34))))));-1);1);"─")
```

***OBS.:** As fórmulas ficaram grandes porque optei em colocar a fórmula do **CORRESP** dentro da fórmula **ÍNDICE**. Mas poderia ter feito como fiz inicialmente, calculando a **CORRESP** noutra célula e entrando na função **ÍNDICE** apenas com seu valor numérico.

Answer (score 1):

Penso que esta fórmula atende a tua necessidade.

Criei uma célula de calculo auxiliar para que a busca seja feita de forma correcta.

**Fórmula Auxiliar**

```
=SE(+INT(X2)-X2<-0,5;ARRED.PARA.CIMA(X2;0);X2)
```

**Fórmula de busca**

```
=+PROCV(Y2;N:T;CORRESP(W2;N$2:T$2;0);3)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nota: Fiz alguns teste e obtive os valores correctos, caso haja algum erro diz para corrigir.

Comment: R.Galamba, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Com relação ao valor 8,86, ao utilizar a sua Fórmula Auxiliar, dá certo porque no teste de hipótese, que dá VERDADEIRO, o resultado será o arredondamento desse valor (9,00), que bate com o espaçamento (primeira coluna) e que que coincidentemente corresponde a linha que contém o valor imediatamente superior (8,89) ao que eu quero. Assim, quando você joga no PROCV a função vai procurar na linha 9 e na coluna da bitola, e retorna o valor correto.

Comment: Porém, quando fui tentar outro valor, como por exemplo o da minha pergunta inicial (6,50), pela sua Fórmula Auxiliar, o teste de hipótese dá FALSO, e retorna o próprio valor (6,50), que mais uma vez, coincidentemente bate com o espaçamento de 6,5 cm (linha 4 da tabela). Assim, ao usar o PROCV da Fórmula de Busca, a função fará uma busca na coluna da bitola e na linha 4, retornando o valor 13,33, quando o valor certo seria 6,67 (linha 13).

Comment: Eu consegui resolver o meu problema com a Função ÍNDICE+CORRESP. Eu consigo obter os resultados que eu quero.

Comment: @allanglayd eu fiz o teste com 6,5 e obtenho o resultado 12,31 não é esse o resultado esperado?

Answer (score 1):

A solução funciona, não sei se é a com o melhor Code Golf possível. Há espaço para diminuir esta fórmula.

Mas com os dados como na seguinte imagem:

[image: Tabela]

#### Dada uma bitola e valor mínimo

Na célula M6 é inserido a coluna com os dados de bitola (de 1 a 6 na linha 4) e na célula M7 o valor do cálculo (no exemplo 6,1).

Com a fórmula `=MÍNIMO(SE(INDIRETO(ENDEREÇO(4;14+CORRESP(M6;O4:T4;0))&":"&ENDEREÇO(18;14+CORRESP(M6;O4:T4;0)))>=M7;INDIRETO(ENDEREÇO(4;14+CORRESP(M6;O4:T4;0))&":"&ENDEREÇO(18;14+CORRESP(M6;O4:T4;0)))))` inserida com <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

O resultado é encontrar na coluna com o valor de bitola 4, o menor valor maior do que 6,1. Que é 6,5.

#### Dado um cálculo, encontrar a bitola

`=INDIRETO(ENDEREÇO(4;MÍNIMO(SE(O5:T18>=M7;COL(O:T)))))` inserida com <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Resultado]

#### Encontrar somente na coluna

Para encontrar na coluna S o valor do cálculo na célula M7

`=MÍNIMO(SE(S:S>=M7;S:S))` inserida com <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Resultado2]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta danieltakeshi. Sua função dá certo, mas pra não ter que fazer as modoficações que você disse necessárias, eu vou utilizar a solução que encontrei. Eu quebrei a minha cabeça e encontrei a solução usando a Função ÍNDICE+CORRESP. Mas vou dar uma analisada nessas suas funções caso eu precise futuramente, principalmente as funções INDIRETO e ENDEREÇO, as quais nunca utilizei. Valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser usada uma fórmula matricial para fazer todos os `SE`'s sem ter que escrever tudo, ficaria assim:

```
{=minimo(se("16,00":"2,42">"8,86";"16,00":2,42"))}
```

Obs.: Substituir os valores pela célula correspondente sem aspas, e usar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> para inserir `{}`.